# Angular 2 label position change

Tags: html, css, angular

I just started practicing Angular 2. I have a checkbox and on the right side label. I have 2 radio buttons, 1-right and 2-left. Depending which radiobutton is selected, I need to move label.

For example: If "left" radiobutton is selected in need to place label on the left side of the checkbox, or vise verse.

Hopefully, I managed to explain good enough :).

Comment: This is not related to Angular. Position and label are quite meaningless tags. You should change the tags to just `css` to make the question visible to the right people.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of it. I was also wondering is there angular way of doing it?!

Comment: After you got a CCS answer it's easy to translate to Angular, if you really want to do it in Angular. Using pure CSS for layout is usually the preferred way. It migt help to add some code that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your reply, it helped me a lot. In the end, I solved it as following:

```html
          <label *ngFor="#item of vm.radioItems">
            <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="vm.label_position.options = item" 
              [checked]="item === vm.options"> 
          <span>To the {{item}}</span>
</label>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'try-checkbox',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <div>
    <span id="myLabel" *ngIf="model.label_position.options==='left'">MyLabel</span>
       <input class="form" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="myLabel" *ngIf="model.label_position.options==='right'">MyLabel</span>
    </div>
  `
})

class App {
     radioItems: 'right left'.split(' '),
     'label_position': { options: 'left'}
                    ...
    }
```

Basically I reused [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/fe0kgemFBtmQOY31b4tw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to move a label depending on which checkbox you picked. Use `ng-class`:

[PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/frllqX?p=preview)

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lefty">
    Left
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="righty">
    Right
  </label>
  <br/><br /><br />
</form>

<p id="myLabel"  
    ng-class="{toLeft: lefty, toRight: righty }">
         My Label!
</p>

<style>
 .toLeft{
   margin-left: 200px;
 }

 .toRight{
   margin-left: 50px;
 }
</style>
```

EDIT: So you want to to move your label to the left or right of a checkbox depending if it has been clicked. I've updated my plnkr. Try this one:

```
   <form name="myForm">
     <span id="myLabel" ng-show="lefty" ng-init="lefty = true">My Label!</span>
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-click="lefty = !lefty; righty = !righty">
     </label>
     <span id="myLabel" ng-show="righty">My Label!</span>
     <br /><br />
   </form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one checkbox, let's call it checkbox1. I need to locate label on the left or right side of that checkbox1. Left or right depends on the selected radio buttons.